# Is there a nuget package for .NET standard with ServiceStack.Text signed?

Tags: nuget, servicestack

I found the signed version for ServiceStack.Text, but only the classic .NET flavor, not the .NET standard. Is it, or will it be available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, .NET Standard packages are never signed as the projects can't be built in all supported platforms with the `dotnet build` command.

In [ServiceStack v5](https://forums.servicestack.net/t/myget-pre-release-packages-upgraded-to-v5/4749) the .NET Standard and .NET Framework packages are now merged into the main **ServiceStack.Text** but only the .NET Framework build is Signed.

Comment: Is there any other option than to unpack the ServiceStack.Text assembly, sign it, pack it again and use an unofficial nuget?

Comment: @ioan You may be able to use a tool like [StrongNamer](https://github.com/dsplaisted/strongnamer) which will let you continue to use it under the commercial free license, whereas any unofficial packages are licensed under the [AGPL / FOSS License Exception](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/master/license.txt). What use-case is requiring the need to use .NET Standard Signed packages?

Comment: I have to use it in a commercial application with the licensed ServiceStack framework, which I need to port to .NET Core. The application must use signed assemblies, so all the dependencies must also be signed.

Comment: @ioan Is this a technical reason why a .NET Core App must use Signed assemblies or this is a policy decision, if so what's the rationale for mandating it?

Comment: It is rather a policy decision

Comment: @ioan I hope whoever's enforcing this policy is aware that Microsoft has issued a warning that you [should not rely on Strong Naming for Security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/strong-named-assemblies).

Comment: I will bring this up to the decision makers